# How to show result of missing date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a query but it does not show me output proper, i want to query for fetching data from my database and find out missing dates.
following is my database and fields.Table name "attendance"

```
 login                  logout                 hrs      eid

 2017-01-11 08:30:00    2017-01-11 17:30:00  09:00:00    1      
 2017-01-12 08:30:00    2017-01-11 17:30:00  09:00:00    1      
 2017-02-01 08:30:00    2017-01-11 17:30:00  09:00:00    1     
 2017-02-02 08:30:00    2017-01-11 17:30:00  09:00:00    1      
 2017-03-02 08:30:00    2017-01-11 17:30:00  09:00:00    1     
 2017-03-11 08:30:00    2017-01-11 17:30:00  09:00:00    1
```

This is the Query that I was trying

```
SELECT eid,count(*) as days_count, MONTHNAME(login), YEAR(login) 
FROM attendence
WHERE eid=1 
GROUP BY monthname(login),year(login);
```

Comment: any codes ?? It means did you tried anything ??

Comment: sir, i am trying but not yet proper.

Comment: SELECT eid,count(*) as days_count, MONTHNAME(login), YEAR(login) fROM attendence where eid=1 group by monthname(login),year(login);

Comment: Create a month, year table to store it, then right join this table get what you want.

Comment: ok I will try this.and sir I want to show missing date in per months

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: result like that.   absent days 2017-01-01.... 2017-01-10 and 2017-01-13.....2017-01-31

Comment: because of id 1 is present 2017-01-11 and 2017-01-12